# Which JMX Metrics gives the health of a kafka cluster?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx

I want to know whether Kafka broker is up or not? I have enabled JMX in Kafka but couldn't find any Mbean name that can provide me the status of Kafka. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things to check health of a cluster, both of which are individual Mbeans and will need to be aggregated over the entire cluster

- Is there only one controller
- Are there no out-of-sync replicas

You may also want to externally port check the brokers from the environments you want to produce and consume from